# How to remove the line formed by joining empty points in a graph? The graph's x axis is break type

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have made a graph using axis break such as from range 0-2 and from 10-16 in x-axis. And the plot type is line graph. But using typ='l' connects the empty data points in the graph with a line (which shows the break between the two ranges). When i use typ="c", I can see the line formed by joining the empty points in my graph. But I want to remove it.. How to do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide the code you have tried until now and a sample data with `?dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add an `NA` value in between. For example, if you have a vector `x`:

```
x <- c(1:5, 10:15)
plot(x, type="l")
```

R will join all the lines. Changing the `type` to "c" doesn't really help. But if you add NA in the place where you want the gap, you'll get two interrupted lines.

```
x <- c(1:5, NA, 10:15)
plot(x, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: I have given an example of my code, if u change the type to line, it connects all the points, how can I avoid in this case: x <- c(9.45, 8.78, 0.93, 0.47, 0.24, 0.12)
y <- c(10.72, 10.56, 10.35, 10.10, 9.13, 6.72)
xgap <- ifelse(x > 8, x-6, x)
#Possibly you'd want to check if there are values between 2 and 8.
plot(xgap, y, col='blue', t="p", xlab= 'x', ylab='y, z', xaxt="n")
xat <- pretty(xgap)
xat <- xat[xat!=2]
xlab <- ifelse(xat>2, xat+6, xat)
axis(1,at=xat, labels=xlab)
library(plotrix)
axis.break(1,2,style="slash")

Comment: Like I said, add NA where you want the gap to appear. Do this for both `x` and `y`: `xgap <- c(xgap[1:2], NA, xgap[3:6]);
y <- c(y[1:2], NA, y[3:6])
`